# Interface inheritance and generic interfaces force explicit casts?

Tags: c#, generics, inheritance, interface, type-inference

I have a much more complicated issue, but I've boiled it down to the following simple example:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace Sandbox
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            IFactory<IProduct> factory = new Factory();
        }
    }

    class Factory : IFactory<Product>
    {

    }

    class Product : IProduct
    {

    }

    interface IFactory<T> where T : IProduct
    {

    }

    interface IProduct
    {

    }
}
```

All is well and dandy... except that I get this error.

Error   1   Cannot implicitly convert type `Sandbox.Factory` to `Sandbox.IFactory<Sandbox.IProduct>`. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)   c:\~~\Program.cs    12  42  Sandbox

Anyone willing to provide insight into why this is the case? I'm sure Jon Skeet or Eric Lippert could explain in a heartbeat why this is, but there has to be someone that not only understands WHY this can't be inferred, but can explain how best to solve this situation.

Follow up question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6390728/why-is-listt-not-valid-on-an-covariant-interface-myinterfaceout-t)

Comment: As it turns out, Eric Lippert and Jon Skeet have explained this in a heartbeat quite a number of times. You'll probably trip and find one such explanation if you search for `interface + covariance`.

Comment: Follow-up questions should be asked as separate questions (Do link them together though.)

Comment: The answer to your follow-up question is that *covariance requires that return types be covariant* in the type parameter.  `List<T>` isn't covariant, you can't treat a `List<Product>` as a `List<IProduct>`, because `List<Product>` has no `Add(IProduct)` method.  You could return `IEnumerable<T>` though, and it would work, since `IEnumerable<Product>` is usable anywhere `IEnumerable<IProduct>` is expected.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is because `Factory` is an `IFactory< Product>` and what you are assigning it to is a `IFactory< IProduct>`, and since `IFactory` is not [covariant](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_Sharp_4.0#Covariant_and_contravariant_generic_type_parameters), you cannot cast a generic of subtype to a generic of supertype.

Try making `IFactory< out T>`, which should make the following assignment work.

**EDIT**:

@Firoso, in your factory interface you are trying to create a list, in which you can write to. If your interface is covariant you can not write to anything, because of the following:

```
List<object> list = new List<string>(); //This is not possible by the way
list.Add(new {}); //Will fail here because the underlying type is List<string>
```

You should ignore covariance in your case and just create assign to an `IFactory<Product>`instead or change factory to inherit `IFactory<IProduct>`instead, I recommend the latter but it is up to you

Comment: oh, it's a covariance issue, that makes sense :-P

Comment: This is closer to my intended answer, please follow up at the link above and I will mark it as answer.

Comment: The explanations given by the others are ok, just accept them but thank you :)