# Is it possible for these classes to implement these interfaces?

Tags: c#, generics, interface, covariance

I am trying to create the following classes.

But I am having struggling to get a couple of View Model classes to implement interfaces, as detailed below.

**Data Model Classes:**

```
public interface IPage
{
    string PageTitle { get; set; }
    string PageContent { get; set; }
}
public interface IDatedPage
    : IPage
{
    DateTime PageDate { get; set; }
}



public abstract class Page
    : IPage
{
    public string PageTitle { get; set; }
    public string PageContent { get; set; }
}
public abstract class DatedPage
    : Page
    , IDatedPage
{
    public DateTime PageDate { get; set; }
}



public class AboutPage
    : Page
    , IPage
{
}
public class NewsPage 
    : DatedPage
    , IDatedPage
{
}
```

**Related View Model Classes:**

```
public interface IPageAdminViewModel<T>
    where T : IPage
{
    IPagedList<T> Pages { get; set; }
}
public interface IDatedPageAdminViewModel<T>
    : IPageAdminViewModel<T>
    where T : IDatedPage
{
}


public abstract class PageAdminViewModel<T>
    : IPageAdminViewModel<T>
    where T: IPage
{
    public IPagedList<T> Pages { get; set; }
}
public abstract class DatedPageAdminViewModel<T>
    : PageAdminViewModel<T>
    , IDatedPageAdminViewModel<T>
    where T : IDatedPage
{
}


public class AboutPageAdminViewModel
    : PageAdminViewModel<AboutPage>
    , IPageAdminViewModel<IPage>
{
}

public class NewsPageAdminViewModel
    : DatedPageAdminViewModel<NewsPage>
    , IDatedPageAdminViewModel<IDatedPage>
{
}
```

**The Problem**

I can't get `AboutPageAdminViewModel` to implement `IPageAdminViewModel<IPage>`.

Similarly `NewsPageAdminViewModel` won't implement `IDatedPageAdminViewModel<IDatedPage>`.

> 'AboutPageAdminViewModel' does not implement interface member 'IPageAdminViewModel<IPage>.Pages'. 'PageAdminViewModel<AboutPage>.Pages' cannot implement 'IPageAdminViewModel<IPage>.Pages' because it does not have the matching return type of 'IPagedList<IPage>'.

---

**What I've Tried 1:**

I have tried adding `out` to the generic parameter on the interface definition, like this:

```
public interface IPageAdminViewModel<out T>
    where T : IPage
{
    IPagedList<T> Pages { get; set; }
}
public interface IDatedPageAdminViewModel<out T>
    : IPageAdminViewModel<T>
    where T : IDatedPage
{
}
```

But it gives me the error:

> Invalid variance: The type parameter 'T' must be invariantly valid on 'IPageAdminViewModel.Pages'. 'T' is covariant.

It won't let me add `out` to the `.Pages` property:

> Invalid variance modifier. Only interface and delegate type parameters can be specified as variant.

---

**What I've Tried 2:**

I've learned that [the `out` parameter doesn't play nicely with `List<>`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6390802/1778169), so I tried changing all `IPagedList` properties to `IEnumerable`. But I am still getting;

> 'AboutPageAdminViewModel' does not implement interface member 'IPageAdminViewModel<IPage>.Pages'. 'PageAdminViewModel<AboutPage>.Pages' cannot implement 'IPageAdminViewModel<IPage>.Pages' because it does not have the matching return type of 'IEnumerable<IPage>'.

---

**Update**

I'm trying to break it down into smaller questions of which this is the first:

[Generic parameter - using a concrete type compiles, but an implemented interface does not](https://stackoverflow.com/q/51450416/1778169)

Comment: Why are you implementing interfaces on classes which inherit from classes which implement them?

Comment: I wouldn't normally, but adding this explicitly to the class allowed me to see whether the error message changed as i tinkered with the code.

Comment: Why the downvote please?  I would be nice to get an explanation as the question doesn't fall foul of any guidelines that I'm aware of.

Comment: Could you post your IPagedList interface (I don't know about the downvote)?

Comment: What are you really trying to accomplish here? `Pages` returns a set of `AboutPage` not an `IPage`. This seems like an [XY Problem](http://xyproblem.info/)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Generic parameter - using a concrete type compiles, but an implemented interface does not](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51450416/generic-parameter-using-a-concrete-type-compiles-but-an-implemented-interface)

Comment: @SBFrancies - it's from the original version of Troy Goode's PagedList here: https://github.com/troygoode/PagedList/blob/master/src/PagedList/IPagedList.cs  (I will add it to the question)

Comment: @JSteward - I want to have other types of  `IPage` too - e.g. `ProfilePage`, `InstructionsPage`, etc

Comment: @GeorgeHelyar - yes it is. I'm not intending to double post here, I just realised it might be better to break it down into smaller components (which I mentioned int the update above).  Would it be good form to delete this question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public class AboutPageAdminViewModel
    : PageAdminViewModel<AboutPage>
    , IPageAdminViewModel<IPage>
{
}
```

The two constraints you have on the class contradict one another. `PageAdminViewModel<AboutPage>` says that the `Pages` collection returns a set of `AboutPage`s and will accept only an `AboutPage`. While, `IPageAdminViewModel<IPage>` says that `Pages` returns any `IPage` and can take any `IPage` too. So while one constraint guarantees only `AboutPage` the other constraint opens the door to any `IPage`. In short not allowed, if it were allowed, you could get a `ProfilePage` out of the `Pages` collection simply because it too was an `IPage`. The only way you can get both behaviors is by implementing each `Pages` collection separately.

Comment: "In short not allowed" - the brutal truth :(   Thanks for explaining